# .net DependencyResolver resolves old service

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, nunit

I have two NUnit TesFixture's - TestClass1 & TestClass2 that are derived from one class - TestBase. Setup for each fixture contains:

```
_unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
_unityContainer.RegisterInstance(_dataManager);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(_unityContainer));
```

In tests in each fixture I initalize `_dataManager` with some data.

All tests are testing same model, model constructor contains:

```
var dataManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDataManager>();
```

If i run each TestFixture's separately, each model resolves correct `IDataManager` from `DependencyResolver`. But if i run both TestFixture's together then model that was created in tests from TestClass2 resolves `IDataManager` that was created in TestClass1.

To run tests i use ReSharper. It seems that fixtures share some resources when they are runned together.

What is the reason for such behavior?

Comment: Have you considered not to use the UnityContainer as a service locator, but instead wiring it all up in a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)? This has facilitated testing for me to a great extent.

Comment: Could this be a result of the [quirk with NUnit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesnewkirk/archive/2004/12/04/275172.aspx) where a new instance of the test fixture is not created for each test method?

Comment: Kevin, i don't think so because in my case i have two different fixtures. And first fixture corrupts second one.